# Selecting range and pasting into every nth column

Tags: vba, excel, loops, macros

Working on some code to copy an active range of cells in column E and then paste the range (starting from the same row) into every nth column. The copy selection part works fine but I can't get the right syntax for the pasting part. I tried setting the cells equal to the selection as I wasn't sure on appropriate syntax to paste values of a selection. Any help/guidance is appreciated! Here is my code:

```
Sub Sco__copy()

Dim cpval As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("E163:E" & lastRow).Select
    Set cpval = Selection
End With

For colx = 12 To 1000 Step 7
Cells(lastRow, colx).Value = cpval
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Sco__copy()

Dim cpval As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Set cpval = .Range("E163:E" & lastRow)

    For colx = 12 To 1000 Step 7
        .Range(.Cells(163, colx), .Cells(lastRow, colx)).Value = cpval.Value
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

The idea is that when assigning values, the target range needs to be the same size as the original.

So by extending the with statement and creating a range the same size it should place the cells in every 7th column.

Comment: That works great! Thanks for the help and also the knowledge :) now I know for next time!!

Comment: @IIJHFII glad it works.  Please come back in a few minutes and mark as correct.